# Html multiple select element accessibility

Tags: html, accessibility

In our web application we have a search form which contains a field for which a user can select one or more answers from a list of possible options.  We currently use the "select" html element with the "multiple" attribute set as in the example below:

```css
select {
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<select multiple>
  <option value="A">Alice</option>
  <option value="B">Bob</option>
  <option value="F">Fred</option>
  <option value="K">Kevin</option>
  <option value="M">Mary</option>
  <option value="S">Susan</option>
</select>
```

Feedback from user testing has shown that this solution is confusing for users.  Multiple selection/deselection is performed by holding down the Ctrl key (on windows), however many users were unaware of this.

The element also does not seem to allow for easy use when using just a keyboard - this is obviously an accessibility issue.

Is there a "best practice", accessible way of displaying an input with multiple options to a user?

Comment: Use a set of checkboxes instead?

Comment: I agree with @JamesDonnelly there. Althought drop downs can be used for this, out of the eye of an interaction designer, i 'd say you should go with check boxes instead. People are much more used to tick multiple boxes with checkboxes.

Comment: Another agreement with checkboxes.  However, the original <select> works just fine with keyboards.  It's a learning curve.  Once you know how to do it, and if you use the keyboard often instead of a mouse, it's pretty easy.  The Ctrl key is your friend.  You can arrow up/down to make your first choice then just hold Ctrl down while using up/down to move the "ghost" focus.  Keep holding Ctrl down and hit spacebar to add the item to the selected group.  This always works in firefox but have seen sporadic results in ie and chrome.

Comment: @slugolicious Unfortunately in Chrome if you are keyboard-only user there is no way to select random items, only sequential items holding shift, but not for example item 1 and 3 and 5 separately.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use checkboxes instead. All checkboxes with the same name are one group (in this case `names`).

```css
.row {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Select the Names</legend>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="names_A" name="names[]" value="A" />
    <label for="names_A">Alice</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="names_B" name="names[]" value="B" />
    <label for="names_B">Bob</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="names_F" name="names[]" value="F" />
    <label for="names_F">Fred</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="names_K" name="names[]" value="K" />
    <label for="names_K">Kevin</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="names_M" name="names[]" value="M" />
    <label for="names_M">Mary</label>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <input type="checkbox" id="names_S" name="names[]" value="S" />
    <label for="names_S">Susan</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**Explanation:**
Every checkbox with the same name and the following brackets (`[]`) is on the same group (in the example `names[]`). If you enable one or more checkboxes the `value` of each selected checkbox will be submited. You get the array with all values with `$names = $_POST['names'];`. If you select `Alice` and `Kevin` you get an array with the following content.

```
Array ( [0] => A [1] => K )
```

The code to get the result array (on the post target site):

```
<?php
$names = $_POST['names']);
print_r($names);
```

If you don't select any checkbox of the group `names` the `$_POST['names']` is undefined.

Comment: +1, but I think your answer could be even better if you explained the implications of "are one group" — e.g. how does that arrive at the server and how do you process it compared to multiple selections.

Comment: This checkbox grouping is missing a group label. It needs one in order to be accessible.

Answer (score 3):

Checkboxes is definitely the preferred option here, **but it's not all you need to do**.

Yes, you need to associate the label with each item, but if you have an overall label such as "Who are you friends with?" you need to associate that with the group of checkboxes overall. This is done with a `fieldset` and `legend`.

```html
<fieldset>
   <legend>Who are you friends with?</legend>
   <input type="checkbox" id="alice"><label for="alice">Alice</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="bob"><label for="bob">Bob</label>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be off topic, but if you are already using `jQuery` then there is this [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#multiple) plugin for it that you can use, and it gives a clear feedback to the user which options are currently selected.

If you are using `prototype.js` then theres this [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#multiple-select) plugin that is pretty much similar to the above mentioned "select2", In fact the select2 was forked from chosen, and you can also use chosen with `jQuery`.

Pros:-

- A good decent feedback to the user on the options selected.
- For a very long list of options, provides a search/autocomplete functionality.

Cons:-

- If not already using `jQuery` then the need/overhead to include a library and then its plugin.
- May not work/create conflict with any other library.

Comment: Both not accessible at all... Try using JAWS or ChromeVox screenreader